# What's the correct way of using Google SSO with random URLs (for testing)?

Tags: oauth, google-signin

We use Netlify to deploy our frontend and use deploy previews to test each PR. This means the URLs we use to access our application is random following the format https://deploy-preview-<RANDOM_STUFF>.netlify.app. When we try to log in using Google OAuth, we get this error:

[image]

What's the correct way to handle this? Security is not super important here because it's only staging/qa.

To clarify: Netlify picks up every single branch and PR, and Netlify generates a new URL with <RANDOM_STUFF>. Adding each of them by hand to Google OAuth's configuration is not an option.

Comment: what have you set for javascript origin in google could console for your project.

Comment: Currently it has localhost, staging.example.com (our domain, not example.com), qa.example.com, etc. It *cannot* have the URLs of each deployment for each PR (each has different <RANDOM_STUFF>.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript origin configured for your app must exactly match where you are sending from.

In this case `https://deploy-preview-<RANDOM_STUFF>.netlify.app`

Comment: I understand that at first glance, that's what Google wants, but each PR has a different <RANDOM_STUFF>, so making it match would add a lot of bureaucracy to each PR.

Comment: and PR stays for what?  pull request, if so yes i agree, but this is the way.   why not check around to see if you cant make <RANDOM_STUFF> static